# PHP Find ID in more than one mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem and don't find a way to solve it.

I have this mySQL Table:

product_insert

```
productInsertID | productID | .........
              1 | 1
              2 | 1
              3 | 2
              4 | 3
```

product_insert_options

```
productInsertID | optionsCategory | optionsValue
              1 |               1 | Option1
              1 |               2 | Option2
              1 |               1 | More Option1
              1 |               2 | More Option2
```

Now I have this php Variables

```
$productID = 1
$productOptionArray
[0][optionsCategory] = 1
[0][optionsValue] = More Option1
[1][optionsCategory] = 2
[1][optionsValue] = More Option2
```

Now I search the productInsertID for my php Variables. In this sample it's the ID 1. I can have more than 2 options, and one productInsertID can have more than one inserts.

How can I make it?

Sorry for my bad english.

EDIT (from answer):

It is a little bit difficult. I try with a sample shop cart and hope you now what I mean:

We have a shop with product and product attribute. Now we have this table: shop_cart

```
cartID | productID | userID | ...
   1   |     1     |    1
   2   |     2     |    1
   3   |     1     |    2
   4   |     1     |    1
```

Now we have the attribute. product_attribute

```
attributeID | productID | attribute
     1      |     1     |    Color
     2      |     1     |    Name
```

And we have the Table shop_cart_attribute

```
ID | cartID | attributeID | productID | value
1  |   1    |      1      |      1    |   red
2  |   1    |      2      |      1    |   Tina
3  |   3    |      1      |      1    |   blue
4  |   3    |      2      |      1    |   Tina
5  |   4    |      1      |      1    |   blue
6  |   4    |      2      |      1    |   Nina
```

Now i have this variable:

```
$productID = 1;
$userID = 1;
$productAttributeArray[0]['attributeID'] = 1;
$productAttributeArray[0]['value'] = red;
$productAttributeArray[1]['attributeID'] = 2;
$productAttributeArray[1]['value'] = Nina;
```

Now I search the cartID for my variables. In this sample its the CardID 4. The result must be empty or the cartID

I hope it's the better example.

Comment: Can you give example. Its not clear from your explaination.

Comment: Sorry for the second post. I don't see the edit :). SMA: I hope the new example is better

Comment: Attribute-Value pairs in a table is flexible, but it is ugly to query and does not scale well.  You probably need a "self join" of the attributes table, joined to the other table.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have me a sample? I have try this: SELECT  c.cartID
FROM shop_cart c INNER JOIN shop_cart_attribute a ON (c.cartID=a.cartID) WHERE (a.attributeID = 1 AND a.value = 'red')
AND  (a.attributeID = 2 AND a.value = 'Nina'). THe result is empty.